# Is serialVersionUID inherited by subclasses, if I have default serialVersionUID in superclass

Tags: java, serialization

Is `serialVersionUID` inherited by subclasses, if I have default `serialVersionUID` in superclass? Similar to when the superclass is serializable then subclasses are also serializable.

I had a superclass initially with no default `serialVersionUID` so I was getting:

```
local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3473908186986930430, 
local class serialVersionUID = -7527159820765531130
```

So I added this to the superclass:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

My question is: does serialization consider `serialVersionUID` from superclass when serializing subclasses or not. Do I need to specify `serialVersionUID`  in every subclass explicitly?

Comment: see this [ask] before you ask here

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, but Java serialization is something to be avoided like the plague. If you want to serialize/deserialize Java objects, try protocol buffers, instead: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan 'Avoided like the plague' is putting it far too strongly. J2EE relies on it at a number of critical points for example.

Comment: @EJP, okay, I'll grant that it may be too strong. However, manual serialization is very error-prone and very easy to break backwards compatibility. In places where it is required, I would still recommend using protocol buffers to generate and parse the binary format that you actually serialize instead of using Java's automatic serialization.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan That's not my experience. In my experience (a) no-one has actually read the Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification, so they don't even know what versioning capabilities are supported, and (b) there is a myth floating around that you should change the `serialVersionUID` every time you change the class, which is the reverse of the true case. So they put about FUD like this instead.

Comment: @EJP, even when doing versioning properly, it's very difficult to do it right (you end up writing lots of boilerplate code to parse multiple formats of the data to be able to deserialize older versions). Auto-generating this from an interface definition language that was designed specifically to solve this problem is a much better way to go.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan That's not my experience. I've been using it for 21 years and I have never written any 'boiler-plate code' at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is serialVersionUID inherited by subclasses, if I have default serialVersionUID in superclass?

No it is not inherited, because it is private, and in any case Serialization won't consider it as belonging to the subclass and not use it.

> Similar to when the superclass is serializable then subclasses are also serializable.

It isn't similar. `Serializable` is an interface and it is subject only to the rules of the language. `serialVersionUID` is a special field with its own rules enforced by `ObjectInputStream.`

Comment: `Serialization won't consider it as belonging to the subclass and not use it.`
Could you clarify that last bit: `and not use it`?  Do you mean that the ObjectInputStream will not use the superclass's serialVersionUID?

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy What part of 'not use it' didn't you understand?

Comment: "inherited" is confusing at this point. `serialVersionUID` is `private`, so how can it be inherited (i.e. be visible in subclasses)? Serialization is most likely traversing the class tree upwards to find the closest class with a `serialVersionUID` through *reflection* (and can therefore overcome the principles of visibility and inheritance in the Java language). It is not clear from your answer what happens if a subclass of class which implements `Serializable` has no `private [...] serialVersionUID`: does serialization fail or is the uid taken from the superclass?

Comment: @KarlRichter Very good, I had overlooked that.